# chrome plugin css injection

Tags: google-chrome, css, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Hi i am trying to inject custom css into a page my manifest file is as below

```
{
  "name": "SaneHaveeru",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "This is to properly display haveeru .",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.haveeru.com.mv/*"], 
      "css" : ["proper.css"]
    }
],
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.haveeru.com.mv/"
  ]

}
```

the css i am injecting is

```
.post-frame {
    float: left;
    width: 470px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #292929;
}
```

but it seem that the pages css is overriding my custom css. as seen here 
[image: screen shot of chrom developer tool showing my css being overridden by the pages css] Is their way to force my css changes on to the page ?

cheers 
Nash rafeeq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `!important` at the end of all your css rules...

```
.post-frame {
    float: left !important;
    width: 470px !important;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    line-height: 30px !important;
    color: #292929 !important;
}
```

http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm

Answer (score 1):

Set the style using JavaScript. it will override any page styles.